# How to add text box in google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am new for App script.

Actually, I am trying to create one form with radio button. Once i choose the radio button i need to get the input from user in text box.

I have tried to insert text box in form UI. But in google form there is no option for text box. Is there any other possible way to add text box.

Comment: What do you mean by ```text box```, do you mean to a short answer question by that? Also, what do you mean by ```radio button```? Maybe a picture or an example with no sensitive information will help you clarify your question. Thanks !

Comment: Short answer question i am able to add. But i need to read user input. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: Hi ! I still cannot figure out what you are trying to tell me. You need to get the user answer to a specific question of the form? You are trying to get the responses of the form? Please, clarify further so that I can help you. :)

Comment: Yes, I need to get the user answer to a specific question of the form. Based on user answered value i need to do some other action.

Comment: To get the response to a specific question of your form you could use the methods ```getResponses()``` or ```getItemResponses()``` as shown in [this example of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response). Does this help or solve your question or did you meant something different? Please let me know :D

Comment: Yes i have tried this things. While running the script i could able to get the form response value. I have assigned the script to onformsubmit() trigger. Now i am trying via form and i am not getting the response. Kindly let me know it is possible to read the form responses while running Form?

Comment: What do you mean by ```now I am trying via form``` ? And with ```while running Form```? Do you mean to keep storing responses while people keep submitting the form? Thanks :)

Comment: i have written script to read form responses. While executing script in scrip editor i am able to get responses. But while trying via form am not getting the value on clicking the submit button. I want to get the values on form submit.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample of your script? Are you using an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)? These let you run your functions on timely based or on certain actions. My wild guess is that you are not getting the updated responses because everytime you need to get the responses you have to re run the funciton making it non updatable. However, with an installable trigger you can catch these changes in the form submissions (i.e every time someone submits a form).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
According to the [Sep 4, 2019 response by "GregE"](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/13555878/in-google-forms-how-do-i-put-a-text-box-beside-a-checkbox-to-justify-my-choice-or-to-put-comments?hl=en) (on this [Support.Google.Com page](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/13555878/in-google-forms-how-do-i-put-a-text-box-beside-a-checkbox-to-justify-my-choice-or-to-put-comments?hl=en)), Google Forms does not have that feature.
But if you find a way to do it, please let me know.